# Отдельный параметр проекта для msbuild при сборке решения

Tags: .net, visual-studio, компиляция, msbuild

Можно ли передать параметр компиляции для определенного проекта в решении, но при этом для компиляции указать только решение?

Необходимо что бы в режиме отладки программа собиралась как консольное приложение, а в релизе, как Win32. Или тут поможет только последовательная сборка проектов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну в принципе это можно сделать, хотя для Visual Studio это не вполне поддерживаемый сценарий.

С точки зрения компиляции, .csproj — это полноценный скрипт для MsBuild, и в нём вы можете задавать любые условия. Например, если вы создадите WPF-приложение, откроете .csproj на редактирование, замените строку

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

на

```
<OutputType Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">Exe</OutputType>
<OutputType Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug' ">WinExe</OutputType>
```

Будет создаваться такой исполнимый файл, как вам надо.

---

Минусы: поскольку это для Visual Studio не является поддерживаемым сценарием, у меня в тестовом приложении вывод в консоль не происходил, если запускать программу через <kbd>F5</kbd> (Start Debugging). Если запускать через <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> (Start Without Debugging), всё работает как надо.

Comment: Пусть почти костыль, но мне этого достаточно, собираю через консоль.

Comment: @Yami: Если собираете через консоль, проблем быть не должно.